# Physical meaning of quadratic forms

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators

Let $Q$ be a dense linear subspace of the Hilbert space, $\mathcal{H}$. Then there is a mapping $q: Q \times Q \to \mathbb{C}$, known as a quadratic form. For two states $\psi, \phi \in Q$,and a self-adjoint operator $A$ on $\mathcal{H}$, then

\begin{equation}
q(\psi,A \phi) = \int \overline{\psi(x)} A \phi(x) dx.
\end{equation}

But what is the physical meaning of such a quadratic form between two different states?

More specifically, if $A = T^{00}$ the energy density operator, does this then measure the change of energy required to change the state $\phi \to \psi$?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Meaning of matrix elements](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/531805/meaning-of-matrix-elements)

Comment: Yes and no. Let me change my question to be more specific.